# Creating or using GPG or SSH keys directly in Go

Tags: go, rsa, file-format

Are there any handy examples, libraries, etc. that read/save the RSA PublicKey and/or PrivateKey types from Go's [crypto/rsa](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/) from/to GnuPG or OpenSSH key formats?

It's obviously not hard to write this, but surely a well routine is out there, if not for GnuPG or SSH then for OpenSSL, [which can be converted to those](http://www.sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?post/2010/03/24/Convert-keys-betweens-GnuPG%2C-OpenSsh-and-OpenSSL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ssh-related methods are in [`golang.org/x/crypto/ssh`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)
(or now Dec. 2014: [github.com/golang/crypto/tree/master/ssh](https://github.com/golang/crypto/tree/master/ssh), since Go switches to GitHub!).
Read/Save RSA keys is manage in [`crypto/x509`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/), as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351194/creating-or-using-gpg-or-ssh-keys-directly-in-go/27352912#comment43169128_27352912) by the [OP Jeff Burdges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667457/jeff-burdges).

You can see a good example in this project [`Scalingo/go-ssh-examples`](https://github.com/Scalingo/go-ssh-examples), which implements an ssh server(!) and client.
It is also described in the article "[Writing a replacement to OpenSSH using Go](http://blog.appsdeck.eu/post/104426674353/writing-a-replacement-to-openssh-using-go-1-2)".

Comment: Got it!  The ParseRawPrivateKey in crypto/ssh led me to X.509 : http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/